Proper name for the result of the calculation $ \frac{V - V_{min}}{V_{max} - V_{min}}$
What is the common name for the result of the following operation:
$$\text{normalized}= \frac{V - V_{min}}{V_{max} - V_{min}}$$
Where $V_{min}$ is the lowest possible element on the set, and $V_{max}$ is the largest one, while $V$ is the current element for which we need this value.
I assume that this should be a "normalized value", but I am not sure. We use this operation here and there and I am sure I missing the very basic term for this. Could it be "biased norm"?
Example
For the set: $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, and the value $2$, this thing is
$$\text{normalized}= \frac{2 - 1}{5 - 1}=0.25$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling_(min-max_normalization)

I've seen the terms "min-max scaling," "min-max normalization," and sometimes just "normalization," but I don't like the latter since it can be confused with the one that takes the mean to 0 and the variance to 1. Also, in a mathematical context, this should never be referred to as a norm, since we reserve that word for other types of operations :)

@Raskolnikov, thank you so much for the link, it helps. One thing I am not quite happy with there is the long name, usually people tend to omit some extra words making "scaling" from such terms and this brings some extra mess, since nobody remembers against which range we are scaling. This especially comes in programming where we abbreviate functions and love shorter names. Anyway, thank you, this is the precise answer to my question.

@EstebanG., I couldn't agree more. One related question, I don't like "normalization" term for this one because of another reason, it crosses with "vector normalization" which usually (at least for Euclidean space) involves root of sum of squares calculation. Or I am wrong here and this is a perfect fit, since in one dimension Euclidean space normalization formula perfectly simplifies to this one?

@DamirTenishev, you are not wrong, in the 1d case vector normalization becomes the sign function for non-zero numbers.

@EstebanG., thank you. Indeed. I missed that in formula in question I need a ratio and with normalizing I want a thing with length equal one, which is totally different. It helped a lot.

In programming contexts, I've sometimes called such a function "progress".

@Blue, this is really "out of the Blue" (kidding), what could be the context? I can't figure out any way to get "progress" here. Can you share the application of this?

@DamirTenishev: The value describes the progress $V$ has made along the journey from $V_{min}$ (value $=0$) to $V_{max}$ (value $=1$). Granted, the term makes best connotational sense when $V$ always increases (and/or when $V_{min}$ and $V_{max}$ are conceptualized as $V_{start}$ and $V_{end}$ or $V_0$ and $V_1$ (eg, as with endpoints of an oriented segment or a parameterized curve)), but it's not that big of a leap for my brain to apply it to an arbitrarily-fluctuating $V$. Your mileage may vary. :)

@Blue, I get it. For me this sounds like a mapping, so in code I would call it (in this case) progressMapping or mapProgress. Although, I like your version, as well. Thanks for the explanation!
